# How to deselect a selected row when selecting the new row in a tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i need to deselect the selected cell when the user selecting a new cell. I can do the selecting and deselecting the tableview rows, but the problem is I need to select only one row at a time. I was doing like this now,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell_check.png"]];   

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell.png"]]; 

}
```

but in this i can  select and deselect the same row. But my intention is when selecting a new row if any other cells are selected already it needs to deselected. Can any body help me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a custom icon to the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark when another table row is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378196/how-to-remove-a-custom-icon-to-the-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-when-anothe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A naive solution would be

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  for (int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
      [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
  } 
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell_check.png"]];   

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell.png"]]; 

}
```

Basically you are looping through all cells deselecting them whenever you select a new one.

Comment: seems to be not working..In this case when i select each rows each cell background became white_cell_check.png.then there is no deselection at all.its a grouped table view.having only one section

Comment: by adding    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        
        cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell.png"]]; in to the loop will do the trick .But i need to double click inorder to change the background of the cell

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: sorry now all r selecting.......means i am selecting a row its cell image is changed .not deselecting.when select it again.

Comment: this will deselect the selected row. The OP wants to deselect all the others

Comment: @GabrielePetronella : then I am not sure what should be the best solution, shuold he iteratre to all rows and select them except current one.

Comment: @AKV i am changing the cell image when selecting and deselecting pls note that

Comment: @hacker : What about looping through all and deselecting all but the current one?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `deselectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
          [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: Any difference from my answer?? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code hope it may work you.

```
int rowNumber = [tableCategory numberOfRowsInSection:0];

for (int indexRow = 0 ; indexRow < rowNumber; indexRow++) {

[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexRow inSection:0];

[tableCategory cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] ;

<required indexpath row>)

cell

cell

}
```

Comment: Sorry currently I'm in Mobile so it is not formatted properly.

Comment: The proper code snippet is in the below link which I've posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378196/how-to-remove-a-custom-icon-to-the-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-when-anothe/14378737#14378737

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378196/how-to-remove-a-custom-icon-to-the-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-when-anothe

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  for (int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell.png"]]; 
  }

   cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_cell_check.png"]];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have such selection handling. I assume 2 groups in table view with single selection of options that enables separate selection of one options, i.e 0,1 sections is one group with single selection, 
2 section is another group with single selection 
In Storbyboard I have chosen "Multiple Selection" But here I deselect other rows in given group.

```
  // MARK: - OPTIONS SELECTION HANDLING
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {

        print("Will select row \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section)")

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0: fallthrough
        case 1:
            // Package Options
            // unselect other packages
            tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.forEach({ (indexPath) in
                if indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 1 {
                    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
                }
            })
        case 2:
            // A'la carte Cleaning Options
            // unselect other cleanings
            tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.forEach({ (indexPath) in
                if indexPath.section == 2 {
                    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
                }
            })
          default:
             fatalError("Impossible section number (\(section))!")
        }

        return indexPath
    }
```